# Avoid a lot of conditions inside an If Statement

Tags: java, if-statement, coding-style, readable

I have an if statement like this

```
if(areEqual(a,ax) && areEqual(b,bx) && areEqual(c,cx) && areEqual(d,dx) && areEqual(e,ex) && areEqual(f,fx) && areEqual(g,gx) && areEqual(h,hx) && areEqual(i,ix) && areEqual(j,jx) && areEqual(k,kx)
```

This if the statement includes lots of conditions and it is not readable. How can I avoid this situation? Is there any pipeline pattern for if conditions?

Comment: https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/47789/how-would-you-refactor-nested-if-statements    https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/205803/how-to-tackle-a-branched-arrow-head-anti-pattern

Comment: What do your individual conditions actually look like? Is there some pattern to them?

Comment: I edited the sample code.

Comment: The problem seems to stem, rather, from having 11 pairs of independently-named variables.  Is there some more appropriate way to structure the information?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using Python, you can store all check in a list(say `list1`) and check

```
if sum(list1)==len(list1):
  do something
```

Comment: Thanks for your help but I use Java8

Answer (score 0):

In javascript, if you add true and true together you get 2. Using this information you could put all the conditions in an array and get the sum of it.

```
var conditions = [condition1, condition2, ... ]; -- all conditions go here

var sum = 0; -- works out the sum
for (var i = 0; i < conditions.length; i++) {
    sum += conditions[i];
}

if (sum === conditions.length) {
    console.log("success")
}
```

Comment: Thank for your help but I use Java8